# BFS traversal on multi-way trees?

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, traversal, breadth-first-search, tree-traversal

I've seen samples, codes and references on bfs, however, all of them seems to focus on traversing through binary trees. I want to know if bfs traversal is possible for multi-way trees, if so where can I find coding references for it?

Answer (score 1):

if you clearly understand how `BFS` works, it doesn't matter what kind of tree (or `graph` more specifically) you are dealing with, you can always find a way.

if you are really not clear with how to do BFS in multy-nodes tree, here is my pseudocode for you:

```
     Queue queue; // a de-queue typed data-structure.
     queue.add(root); // root of the tree.

     while -> queue is not empty() :  // traversed untill queue become empty

          tempNode := queue.peek();   // process the peeked item from queue
              queue.pop();

          process -> tempNode.item;

          while -> tempNode.childnode is not null:
                   queue.add(tempNode.childnode)
                   tempNode := tempNode.childnode;

          end of while;

     end of while;
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I searched too, and bfs aren't focus in multi-way trees.
But, references on bfs with **graph** [exists](https://www.guru99.com/breadth-first-search-bfs-graph-example.html). Because multi-way trees are a subset of graphs, you may find your happiness there.

Answer (score 0):

BFS is indeed a traversal that is not specific for *binary* trees, but can be used on any graph. Wikipedia has an entry on [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), and it even offers pseudo code that is intended to work with any graph.

> Input: A graph G and a starting vertex root of G
>
> Output: Goal state. The parent links trace the shortest path back to
> root
>
> ```
>  1  procedure BFS(G, root) is
>  2      let Q be a queue
>  3      label root as discovered
>  4      Q.enqueue(root)
>  5      while Q is not empty do
>  6          v := Q.dequeue()
>  7          if v is the goal then
>  8              return v
>  9          for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
> 10              if w is not labeled as discovered then
> 11                  label w as discovered
> 12                  Q.enqueue(w)
> ```